# SQL sort by desc doesn't work with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I tried to get the latest column id_status with column tahun and semester (the timestamp is all the same so I can't use it), I can do it with this code no problem:

```
SELECT A.id_ips, B.tahun, B.semester, B.id_status FROM data_ips A
LEFT JOIN data_status_mahasiswa B
ON A.id_mahasiswa = B.id_mahasiswa
ORDER BY B.tahun DESC, B.semester DESC
```

| id_ips | tahun | semester | id_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 155324 | 2012 | 2 | 6 |
| 155324 | 2012 | 1 | 7 |
| 155324 | 2009 | 2 | 1 |
| 155324 | 2009 | 1 | 2 |
| 155324 | 2008 | 2 | 9 |
| 155324 | 2008 | 1 | 1 |
| 155325 | 2015 | 2 | 8 |
| 155325 | 2015 | 1 | 3 |
| 155325 | 2010 | 2 | 4 |
| 155325 | 2010 | 1 | 9 |
| 155325 | 2009 | 2 | 9 |
| 155325 | 2009 | 1 | 4 |

But when I try to group by it with column id_ips the data doesn't seem to be ordered anymore...

```
SELECT X.* FROM 
(
    SELECT A.id_ips, B.tahun, B.semester, B.id_status FROM data_ips A
    LEFT JOIN data_status_mahasiswa B
    ON A.id_mahasiswa = B.id_mahasiswa
    ORDER BY B.tahun DESC, B.semester DESC
) AS X
GROUP BY X.id_ips
```

| id_ips | tahun | semester | id_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 155324 | 2008 | 1 | 1 |
| 155325 | 2009 | 1 | 4 |

I've tried to do GROUP BY AND ORDER BY at the same place like these:

```
SELECT A.id_ips, B.tahun, B.semester, B.id_status FROM db_mahasiswa.data_ips A
LEFT JOIN db_mahasiswa.data_status_mahasiswa B
ON A.id_mahasiswa = B.id_mahasiswa
GROUP BY A.id_ips
ORDER BY B.tahun DESC, B.semester DESC
```

And this:

```
SELECT X.* FROM 
(
    SELECT A.id_ips, B.tahun, B.semester, B.id_status FROM data_ips A
    LEFT JOIN data_status_mahasiswa B
    ON A.id_mahasiswa = B.id_mahasiswa
    ORDER BY B.tahun DESC, B.semester DESC
) AS X
GROUP BY X.id_ips
ORDER BY X.tahun DESC, X.semester DESC
```

But it still yield the same result, what I want is this:

| id_ips | tahun | semester | id_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 155324 | 2012 | 2 | 6 |
| 155325 | 2015 | 2 | 8 |

I don't know where is the problem...?

Comment: you need to put the order by on the outer query after `group by`; i'm not sure about mysql but in other database engines the `order by` would be invalid without a `limit` or `top` clause.

Comment: Why do you use `group by`? You are not doing any aggregation. If you want only the top row just use LIMIT 1 after the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @Stu the result is still the same...

Comment: @forpas the data is a lot more than that (different id_ips) so I can't use limit

Comment: Do you expect us to guess what your requirement is? Edit your question and clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas it's the only requirement, I've edited my question (adding data)

Comment: @Stu I've edited my question (adding more data), maybe you would want to help me?

Comment: you can use order by outside the subquery. You don't use any aggregate function so why use group by.

Comment: group by should be done before order by.

Comment: @RahulBiswas I tried it but it doesn't work, because it's grouped first (and then ordered the only one row of grouped id_ips (155324, 155325)), basically order by should be before the group by (it give me error if I do that)

Comment: Please share your desired result.

Comment: What version of mysql you are using? is it 8.0 or higher?

Comment: Please provide your expected output.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur I've edited my question to be clearer to everyone, I might delete and make a new question if this one doesn't get any answer soon

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's much more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT X.*
FROM (SELECT A.id_ips, B.tahun, B.semester, B.id_status
      FROM data_ips A LEFT JOIN 
           data_status_mahasiswa B
           ON A.id_mahasiswa = B.id_mahasiswa
      ORDER BY B.tahun DESC, B.semester DESC
     ) X
GROUP BY X.id_ips;
```

is simply incorrect and should generate a syntax error.  Why?  The `GROUP BY` column in the outer query is inconsistent with the `SELECT` columns.  Happily, this returns an error in almost all databases.

If this is what you want:

> I tried to get the latest column id_status with column tahun and semester (the timestamp is all the same so I can't use it)

Then one method uses window functions:

```
SELECT X.*
FROM (SELECT A.id_ips, B.tahun, B.semester, B.id_status,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.id_ips ORDER BY B.tahun DESC, B.semester DESC) as seqnum
      FROM data_ips A LEFT JOIN 
           data_status_mahasiswa B
           ON A.id_mahasiswa = B.id_mahasiswa
     ) X
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Note that there is no aggregation at all in this query.  You are not "aggregating" anything.  You simply want to choose the correct row, which you do through *filtering* not *aggregation*.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the highest value of tahun, semester and id_status for each id_ips please try aggregation `max()` with `group by` clause.

```
  SELECT X.id_ips,max(X.tahun) as tahun, max(X.semester) as semester, B.id_status  as id_status FROM 
    (
        SELECT A.id_ips, B.tahun, B.semester, B.id_status,id_mahasiswa FROM data_ips A
        LEFT JOIN data_status_mahasiswa B
        ON A.id_mahasiswa = B.id_mahasiswa
        ORDER BY B.tahun DESC, B.semester DESC
    ) AS X
    left jion data_status_mahasiswa B
    on X.id_mahasiswa = B.id_mahasiswa 

    GROUP BY X.id_ips
    ORDER BY X.tahun
```

Comment: sorry but the latest id_status isn't always the largest/max, as seen in the question table no 1 (id_status ranged from 1 to 9). I tried the other answer and it worked to me, thank you btw!

Comment: I found my mistake and revised my answer. But if your MySQL version is 8.0 then surely Gordon's is the right answer. That's why I have asked for the version. Thanks for the vote and Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for your desired results is not to use `group by` since you're not aggregating anything, you are simply selecting a row for each id_ips based on the ordering of two subsequent columns, for which `row_number` is ideal:

```
with cte as (
    select *, Row_Number() over(partition by id_ips order by tahun desc, semester desc) rn
    from t
)
select id_ips, tahun, semester, id_status
from cte
where rn=1
```